# Is there a full implementation of the HTML5 Canvas object for GWT?

Tags: gwt, html, canvas

I'm looking to perform some dynamic charting based on a model via GWT on HTML5 compliant browsers.

I know that the following library exists :

[GWT Canvas](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-canvas/issues/list)

The problem is that this library does not support drawing text within the canvas so I can draw lines but no write text on my charts.

I haven't been able to find any other plugin that works with the Canvas in GWT (which is really odd given the HTML5 push by Google).

Does such a component exist?

Comment: It should be pretty easy to add support for this to the GWT Canvas project (and help others in the process!) Start by adding the relevant methods for text drawing (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/drawing_text_using_a_canvas) to the `CanvasImpl` class (http://code.google.com/p/gwt-canvas/source/browse/trunk/gwt/canvas/client/impl/CanvasImpl.java) -- looks like you're not the only one who's waiting for this either: http://code.google.com/p/gwt-canvas/issues/detail?id=14

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take a look at the official canvas support in gwt-incubator. http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit-incubator/wiki/GWTCanvas

Comment: There is no support for text drawing there either.

Answer (score 1):

The GWT incubator seems to be more focussed on browser support. If you don't require this and wish to use more of the HTML5 Canvas features, see:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/html5canvas/